# Script running forever

Tags: shell-script

could you please provide me insight on why the following script runs forever even after last echo statement ran successfully? Thank you for your help.

```
cd /app/pme/${property:DeployEnv}/ruleengine
./stop.sh
unzip -o ruleengine.app.zip
unzip -o ruleengine.${property:DeployEnv}.zip
dos2unix *.sh
echo begin chmod
chmod ugo+rx *.sh
echo end chmod
echo begin run.sh
./run.sh
echo end run.sh
cd /app/pme/${property:DeployEnv}/ruleengine
pwd
echo start rm commands
rm ruleengine.app.zip
rm ruleengine.${property:DeployEnv}.zip
echo end rm commands
exit
```

Comment: The reason is probably within the `run.sh` script you're invoking. Why don't you post the contents of that?

Comment: Do this. `set -v on` then run this script and show us the results. then do `set -o verbose`.

Comment: An easy thing to do will be to add the statement `set -x` where you want to start debugging from.  That will show you exactly what is going on with different commands.

Comment: run.sh is not our script. This script runs on a different server, and they asked us to include this command. However, I will include set -v on and will let you know the results. Thank you.

Comment: The following error I see after I added the set -v on. The error is " Exception in thread "FileUpdateEventThread" java.lang.NullPointerException". It looks like there are some isues with the Java code that is running on the server. I will inform the Application DEV team about it. Thank you very much everybody for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To debug a Bash script, which I'm assuming the above actually is Bash, simply run it like this:

```
$ bash -x <script.sh>
```

You can also enable disable debugging message by adding `set -x` and `set +x` around blocks of code where you'd like to see more verbose info.

#### Example

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "msg1"
echo "msg2"
set -x
echo "msg3"
echo "msg4"
set +x
echo "msg5"
```

Then when I run it:

```
$ ./my.sh 
msg1
msg2
+ echo msg3
msg3
+ echo msg4
msg4
+ set +x
msg5
```

We can see which commands are running in the above output. The command is displayed with a plus sign prefixing the command, followed by its output.

```
+ echo msg3
msg3
```

Only the block of commands wrapped inside the `set ..` commands are displayed like this.

Answer (score 1):

I suggested in a comment above, and it looks like it led to identifying the issue, putting it here because this could be useful for debugging.

> Do this. `set -v on` then run this script and show us the results. then do `set -o verbose`

Author identified an Exception being thrown by a Java program.

Answer (score -1):

All the echo lines should have their arguments in quotes, eg:

```
echo 'end rm commands'
```

Comment: This is not necessary and is not related to the issue, echo can take multiple arguments.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to put this one as comment.